# Latest google security checkup system shows "Unverified Developer"

Tags: google-apps, google-workspace

Latest google security checkup system shows "Unverified Developer" on our app, that has been in google market place for a long time and it's verified, but we as a developer is not and clients are starting to ask questions, why and what is the reason.
Tried to find any information about 3'rd party developers verification / certification process and can't find anything.

Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/client-verification#requesting_verification) about getting verified as a developer in the `Google Apps Script` but it points to a [form](https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification) that doesn't seem related to just `Apps Script`, but to `OAuth Clients` in general.

So properly fill out this form:
https://support.google.com/code/contact/oauth_app_verification
and cross your fingers.